# Please Explain what's happening with appending a document fragment

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm wondering whats happening here. I have a document fragment (which comes from a template) and I'm appending that fragment to the Dom (document.body). Before doing so I get a reference to all the fragment's children and console log that out. Then I do the append and console.log the same array and it is now empty.

Does anybody know whats going on here? Why that array is now empty after appending the fragment.

```
<html>
<body>

<template id="templateEl">
  <div>Div Content</div><span>Span Content</span>
</template>

<script>

var el = document.querySelector("#templateEl");
var fragment = document.importNode(el.content, true);
var children = fragment.children;

console.log(children);
document.body.appendChild(fragment);
console.log(children);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.importNode` creates a copy.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `importNode()` method, you are creating a copy of the element, as a [**document fragment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment).

Since you are passing `true` as the **deep** parameter of the import method (third), this fragment contains the copied element's children. So you can log it correctly.

But, when you append this fragment to the body, the children are extracted from the fragment, and appended to the selected element(in your case, the body):

[(from MDN's docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

> Various other methods can take a document fragment as an argument (e.g., any Node interface methods such as Node.appendChild and Node.insertBefore), in which case ***the children of the fragment are appended or inserted, not the fragment itself.***

Since the `fragment` variable is a reference to the fragment, its `children` property becomes empty.